# Photoshop Scripting - Not correctly resizing

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have written a script in Javascript for photoshop which gets user input (number of boxes on the desktop) then converts it into pixel sizes. The problem is on resizing, the layer doesn't change to that amount, it changes by that amount. Eg. microsoftbox starts at 800*800 then should change to 500*500 but adds that on to equal 1300*1300.

```
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
//Get all input
var microsoftboxes = prompt("How many boxes for microsoft?");
var gamesboxesx = prompt("How many across boxes for games?");
var gamesboxesy = prompt("How many down boxes for games?");
var adobeboxes = prompt("How many boxes for adobe?");
var filesboxes = prompt("How many boxes for files?");
var toolsboxes = prompt("How many boxes for tools?");
var recycleboxes = 1;
//Add percentage on and convert to pixel num
var mb = microsoftboxes * 75;
mb = mb + (mb * 0.04);
var gbx = gamesboxesx * 75;
gbx = gbx + (gbx * 0.04);
var gby = gamesboxesy * 75;
gby = gby + (gby * 0.04);
var ab = adobeboxes * 75;
ab = ab + (ab * 0.04);
var fb = filesboxes * 75;
fb = fb + (fb * 0.04);
var tb = toolsboxes * 75;
tb = tb + (tb * 0.04);
var rb = recycleboxes * 75;
rb = rb + (rb * 0.04);
//vars for change size
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var m = doc.layers.getByName('microsoft');
var g = doc.layers.getByName('games');
var a = doc.layers.getByName('adobe');
var t = doc.layers.getByName('tools');
var f = doc.layers.getByName('files');
var r = doc.layers.getByName('recycle');
m.resize(mb, 73, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
g.resize(gbx, gby, AnchorPosition.TOPCENTER);
a.resize(ab, 73, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
f.resize(fb, 73, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
t.resize(tb, 73, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
r.resize(rb, 73, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q24aB.jpg)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLp2K.png)

---UPDATE---
I have managed to work out that it is despite being set to pixels, changing by the percentage. Eg. files should have been set to 78 but it was set to

```
250 (the current value) * 0.78(78 as a percentage) = 195
```

Files was being set to 195 pixels. Any way I can fix this?

Code is now:

```
var startru = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
var starttu = app.preferences.typeUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS;
//Get all input
var microsoftboxes = prompt("How many boxes for microsoft?");
var gamesboxesx = prompt("How many across boxes for games?");
var gamesboxesy = prompt("How many down boxes for games?");
var adobeboxes = prompt("How many boxes for adobe?");
var filesboxes = prompt("How many boxes for files?");
var toolsboxes = prompt("How many boxes for tools?");
var recycleboxes = 1;
//Add percentage on and convert to pixel num
var mb = microsoftboxes * 75;
mb = mb + (mb * 0.04);
var gbx = gamesboxesx * 75;
gbx = gbx + (gbx * 0.04);
var gby = gamesboxesy * 75;
gby = gby + (gby * 0.04);
var ab = adobeboxes * 75;
ab = ab + (ab * 0.04);
var fb = filesboxes * 75;
fb = fb + (fb * 0.04);
var tb = toolsboxes * 75;
tb = tb + (tb * 0.04);
var rb = recycleboxes * 75;
rb = rb + (rb * 0.04);
//vars for change size
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var m = doc.layers.getByName('microsoft');
var g = doc.layers.getByName('games');
var a = doc.layers.getByName('adobe');
var t = doc.layers.getByName('tools');
var f = doc.layers.getByName('files');
var r = doc.layers.getByName('recycle');
m.resize(mb, 85, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
g.resize(gbx, gby, AnchorPosition.TOPCENTER);
a.resize(ab, 85, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
f.resize(fb, 85, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
t.resize(tb, 85, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
r.resize(rb, 85, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);
app.preferences.rulerUnits = startru;
app.preferences.typeUnits = starttu;
```

Comment: Guess this is too hard!

Comment: its been a long time since i've done this - but I'm pretty sure resize requires the delta.  so try giving it -300 (e.g. want to take 300 from 800 to get 500)

Comment: So change my code to  `m.resize(-mb, -73, AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);` I'll try it now. If it works write as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I've updated post.

Comment: I could use the original values as 100 so the percentage would be equal to the original value but I was looking for problem I my code. I'll try then add as an answer unless someone does it first.

Comment: you have set preferences for units, but try setting the units specifically on the variables passed to resize. something like:  UnitValue(10,'px')

Comment: `m.resize(mb, 85+'px', AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);` Like this or something like `mb = 10,'px';`?

Comment: something like m.resize(new UnitValue(mb,'px'), new UnitValue(10,'px'), AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT);  Sorry, without an active photoshop dev environment I am kind of stabbing in the dark from memory

Comment: Thanks. Will try when I get back!

Comment: Sorry, works the same as it did before. Might have to scrap this idea. Thanks for the time though

Comment: I know it will work.  I've done it a ton of times.   But I don't even have access to my old code to look it up at the moment :(

Comment: Okay. What should I do?

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK that is how the resize method works for ArtLayer Objects.  Per the JS scripting guide:  "Resizes the layer to the specified dimensions (as a percentage of its current size) and places it in the specified position."  I suggest copying your layer to a new document, using resizeImage to get to the proper dimensions, then copy back to your original document.  I will provide an answer that demonstrates how to do this shortly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the resize method for ArtLayer objects are explicitly expecting percent values and can't accept pixel values for the resize.  I'm sure there's a formula to use the current layer's size to determine the percentage you need to get to a new specific size, but I think the path of least resistance is to

1. Duplicate the layer into a new document
2. Resize it to the exact pixel dimensions you need
3. Copy that layer back to the original document

Below is a sample I wrote to accomplish exactly that.  It's not a copy/paste solution to your problem, but rather an illustration using the idea of what you want to do.  I think it should be fairly easy to modify this code to suit your exact needs.

```
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
var activeDoc = app.activeDocument;
//store the active document's resolution for when we create the temp doc
var res = activeDoc.resolution;

//capture the existing color mode for the temp doc
var newDocMode;
switch(activeDoc.mode) {
    case DocumentMode.RGB:
        newDocMode = NewDocumentMode.RGB;
        break;
    case DocumentMode.CMYK:
        newDocMode = NewDocumentMode.CMYK;
        break;
}

//my preference to store sizes as a JSON object
var msboxSizes = {
    sm: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    },
    md: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    }, 
    lg: {
        width: 800,
        height: 800
    }
};

//target our layer
var msboxLayer = activeDoc.artLayers.getByName("microsoftbox");

//make it the active layer
activeDoc.activeLayer = msboxLayer;

//get the bounds of the layer so we can create a new doc the same size as the image on this layer
var msboxSize = activeDoc.activeLayer.bounds;

//use the bounds to determine the width and height of the layer
var msboxWidth = (msboxSize[2].value - msboxSize[0].value).toFixed(0);
var msboxHeight = (msboxSize[3].value - msboxSize[1].value).toFixed(0);

//convert those values back into pixels
msboxWidth = new UnitValue(msboxWidth, "px");
msboxHeight = new UnitValue(msboxHeight, "px");

//copy our layer to the clipboard
msboxLayer.copy();

//create a new doc that is the same size, resolution and color mode as the layer we want to resize
var tempDoc = app.documents.add(msboxWidth, msboxHeight, res, "Temp Doc", newDocMode, DocumentFill.TRANSPARENT);

//set the temp doc as the active document
app.activeDocument = tempDoc;
//paste the layer into the temp doc
tempDoc.paste();

//store the different size obj keys in an array (could use array of objects and skip this bit)
var resizes = ["lg","md","sm"]
//loop through resizing to each size in the array, copy and paste them as layers into the original document
for (i = 0; i < resizes.length; i++) {
    var newWidth = msboxSizes[resizes[i]].width;
    var newHeight = msboxSizes[resizes[i]].height;

    app.activeDocument = tempDoc;
    tempDoc.resizeImage(newWidth, newHeight, res, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC);
    tempDoc.activeLayer.copy();

    app.activeDocument = activeDoc;
    activeDoc.paste();
}

//close the temp doc and dont save it
tempDoc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```